# Ayuda con la funcion SUMA en Haskell ghci

Tags: funciones, haskell

Uso ghci en notepad++

Tengo la siguente funcion:

```
suma :: (Integer, Integer) -> (Integer)
suma (x,y) = x + y
```

Corriendo esta en la consola:

```
*Main> suma (3,5)
```

Me arroja el siguente error:

```
<interactive>:6:1: error:
    * Variable not in scope: suma :: (Integer, Integer) -> t
    * Perhaps you meant `sum' (imported from Prelude)
```

Comment: No conozco `haskell`, pero ¿has investigado? por ejemplo esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39403857/4092887) podría ayudarte.

Comment: SI, justamente esa fue la que vi ni bien googlie mi problema. Pasa que cada caso es muy particular parece...

Answer (score 0):

Encontre mi propio error. Quizas a alguien le sirva.

Al principio habia escrito mal la fincion `SUMAR`y haskell guardo ese error.
Hay que volver a recompilar despues de reescribir la funcion.
Primero en la consola hay que poner `:r` y despues volver a invocar la funcion con sus respectivos parametros `sumar (3,5)`

Comment: La verdad es que es muy confuso que en el título pongas `SUMA`, en el error ponga `suma` y que ahora pongas en la solución `sumar`.

Comment: Recuerda guardar los cambios (con :r) antes de recompilar el código, de lo contrario no te va a guardar los cambios.

Answer (score 0):

Los parametros en haskell no tienen esa sintaxis, al escribir suma (x,y) te va a funcionar pero en verdad estas pasando una tupla. La sintaxis correcta en este caso seria:

```
suma :: Int -> Int -> Int
suma x y = x + y
```

Como ves, en haskell cada para metro se separa por espacios, igualmente al llamar a la función seria:

```
suma 2 2
```